# How to integrate Amazon in AppLovin Max

Tags: ios

`https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/flutter/mediation-adapters/android?network=AMAZON_MARKETPLACE_NETWORK

```
nitialize the Amazon SDK
```

The Amazon Publisher Services SDK requires that you initialize it outside of MAX SDK:
Copy
Dark Mode
// Amazon requires an 'Activity' instance
AdRegistration.getInstance( "AMAZON_APP_ID", this );
AdRegistration.setAdNetworkInfo( new DTBAdNetworkInfo( DTBAdNetwork.MAX ) );
AdRegistration.setMRAIDSupportedVersions( new String[] { "1.0", "2.0", "3.0" } );
AdRegistration.setMRAIDPolicy( MRAIDPolicy.CUSTOM );

I don't know what that means，How does Amazon integrate into max?
Does amazon support flutter？

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.